# Why layout does not integrated

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-web-api, katana

I have a ASP.NET Web API that run on Katana and use Razorengine for generating views.

So I created a view without layout and it works as expected.
**View.cshtml**

```
<h2>View</h2>
```

**On browser** 
[image]

So when I am going to add a layout like:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>View</h2>
```

After the request I've got just a blank site.

What am I doing wrong?
[image]

**Update**

The controller code:

```
public class CustomersController : ApiController
  {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("customers")]
    public IHttpActionResult View()
    {
      return new ViewResult(Request, @"Customers\View", null);
    }

  }
```

and _**Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

But when I replaced the layout with other structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  @RenderBody()

  </body>
</html>
```

Then it works. The layout template is wrong.

Comment: Do you have any error in the layout file ?

Comment: Why are you accesing to ""Customers" url?, have you change RouteConfig?, I say it because you have "View" as title of your page so if you don´t change anything of your view as ViewBag or RouteName you should access like:  localhost:12345/Controller/View instead if your are using api, remember you need to do blank constructor into controller

Comment: Does `_Layout.cshtml` has `@RenderBody()` in it?

Comment: Why are you returning views from API controllers? MVC is suited for that a lot better.

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: @zero_coding I suspect one of the MVC features (`@Scripts.Render` or `@RenderSection`) will not work in your set up

Comment: @trailmax I want to have combine asp.net mvc with asp.net web api that use OWIN specification. I want to have a self host server. What I want to do is, a login site that based on asp.net mvc and after successfull login, further site based on angular.